# Best way to access different fonts?

Tags: fonts, font-face, font-size, webfonts, truetype

been looking online and need to find 4 diff extensions to one font...
i cant seem to find the 4 of the same extension.
WebFont.eot, WebFont.woff, WebFont.ttf and WebFont.svg

any sites you guys know of?

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to http://www.khazar.com/academics/portal/canada/2011spring/mart369/webfonts/
and follow the 'How To'